# How to Read data from dynamic Facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api

I am new to C# (learning it nowadays), and have choosen FB and C# Facebook SDK as a test project to learn things (maybe not a good idea). So here is the issue.

I am using VS 2010, ASP.NET MVC 3

I am using the following code to retreive some data from the FB

```
public ActionResult FBLandingPageFinal ( string accessToken )
        {
 var newfb = new FacebookClient ( accessToken );
 dynamic FQLResultSet = newfb.Get ( "fql", new { q = "select uid, name from user where is_app_user = 1 and uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())" } );
 ViewBag.FQLResultSet = FQLResultSet;

         }
```

Now this return data in json format in the following format

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "uid": XXXXX, 
      "name": "User Name 1"
    }, 
    {
      "uid": XXXXX, 
      "name": "User Name 2"
    }, 
    {
      "uid": XXXXX, 
      "name": "User Name 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Upto this point everything is working fine, now can anyone guide me how extract data from this viewbag object on my aspx page ( **i am not using razor syntax**)

Now on the aspx page this what i am trying to achieve

```
<ul>

<%
 foreach (var item in ViewBag)
{ 
%>

<li><a href="#" ><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<%={uid from viewbag}%>/picture" alt="" /></a> <%{name from ViewBag} %></li>
<%
}

%>
```

Any advise will be a real help and i appreciate the time and effort you guys putting up in reading such a long question as i have tried to explain everything what i am doing.

Looking forward for guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deserialize that JSON into an object before putting it into the ViewBag. You can use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx), like so

```
public ActionResult FBLandingPageFinal (string accessToken)
    {
     var newfb = new FacebookClient (accessToken);
     dynamic jsonResult= newfb.Get ( 
                             "fql", 
                              new { 
                               q = "select uid, name from user where is_app_user = 1 and uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())" 
                                  });
     var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     ViewBag.FQLResultSet = serializer.Deserialize<ImageSet>(jsonResult);
    }

// You have to define this class
public class FbImage
{
   public string string name {get; set;}
   public string string uid {get; set;}
}

// And this one
public class ImageSet
{
   public List<FbImage> images {get; set;}
}
```

And then, in your View, here's what you do:

```
<ul>
<%foreach (var item in ViewBag.FQLResultSet.images ){%>
<li>
   <a href="#" >
    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<%={item.uid}%>/picture" alt="" />
   </a> <%{item.name} %>
</li>
<%}%>
```